# Having trouble outputing console.log in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When I open up the following file with my firefox browser, nothing is outputted on my screen. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
        var mystring="hello world";
        console.log(mystring);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`console.log()` does not write on the webpage (for that you need `document.write("your text here")`.

To view that text, make sure you enable and open "Developer tools" in firefox and go to the "console" tab. Refresh the page and you will see the text there!

For more info, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

This might help you also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console